# Angular reactive form dropdown without select and option tags

Tags: html, css, angular, dropdown, angular-reactive-forms

I ran into difficulty styling my dropdown : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select#Styling_with_CSS

> The select element is notoriously difficult to style productively with CSS.

in summary none of the hacks you can use on the option and select tags are worth their salt even in combination.

I'd love to continue using reactive forms but I wish to purify my html and css by using only `<div>` tags to draw up and use my dropdown in a reactive form.

is this possible?

here is my code as it exists today.

```js
// this.statusForm = this.fb.group({
//    status: ['Delivered', Validators.required]
// });
```

```html
<form [formGroup]="statusForm">
   <select formControlName="status">
      <option value="Delivered">Delivered</option><!--&#xf00c;-->
      <option value="Cancelled">Cancelled</option><!--&#xf05e;-->
      <option value="UndeliveredTechnicalissue">Undelivered/Technical issue</option><!--&#xf00d;-->
   </select>
</form>
```

the js is just the FormBuilder hydration.

I can gather/ console.log() the value using

```
 this.statusForm.value.status;
```

Comment: Is this any help to you i built it ages ago because of the styling of HTML Selects, https://www.jsclasses.org/package/558-JavaScript-Create-select-inputs-that-can-be-styled.html

Answer (score 3):

You create the "options" part as ul>li or div and then style it accordingly.

The trick is to hide/show this part on mouse click or keyboard interaction, but for this you can use a boolean variable (here `expanded`).

**Here a [working Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dfy6hf).**

If you want to look at the code in just one page, have a look to the code below:

**template**

```
<div class="select-container">
  <input type="text"      
      [id]="customId"
      [placeholder]="placeholder"
      [value]= "selectedValue"
      [disabled]="disabled"
      (click)="showOptions()"/>
  <ul class="select-menu box" role="listbox" *ngIf="expanded">   
      <li role="option"
          *ngFor="let option of options; let i = index;" 
          [id]="customId + '-option-' + i" 
          [title]="option.label"
          class="option-item"
          [ngClass]="{ 'selected': activeItemIndex === i }"
          (click)="selectItem(option)">
          <span> {{option.label}}</span>
      </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**component**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'form-select',
  templateUrl: './form-select.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./form-select.component.scss'],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
      multi: true,
      useExisting: forwardRef(() => FormSelectComponent)
    }
  ]
})
export class FormSelectComponent implements ControlValueAccessor{

  public selectedValue = '';
  public disabled = false;
  public value: string;

  @Input()
  label: string;

  @Input()
  formCtrl: AbstractControl;

  @Input()
  pipe: { type?: string; params?: any };

  @Input()
  options: {key: string, label: string}[] = [];

  @Input()
  customId: string;

  @Input()
  placeholder: string;

  public expanded = false;

  public activeItemIndex: number;


public onChange(newVal: T) {}

public onTouched(_?: any) {}

public registerOnChange(fn: any): void {
    this.onChange = fn;
  }

public registerOnTouched(fn: any): void {
    this.onTouched = fn;


writeValue(value: string) {
    if (value && this.options) {
      const match = this.options.find(
        (item: { type?: string; params?: any }, index: number) => {
          if (item.key === value) {
            this.activeItemIndex = index;
            return true;
          }
        }
      );
      this.selectedValue = match ? match.label : '';
    }
  }

  showOptions() {
    if (!this.disabled) {
      this.expanded = true;
    }
  }

  selectItem(item: {key: string, label: string}) {
    this.value = item.key;
    this.expanded = false;
    this.selectedValue = item.label;
    this.onChange(item.key);
  }
}
```

**scss styles**

```
.select-container {
  position: relative;

  .input-container {
    i {
      position: absolute;
      top: 1rem;
      right: 1rem;
    }
    input[type='text'] {
      overflow-x: hidden;
      white-space: nowrap;
      text-overflow: ellipsis;
      padding-right: 2rem;
    }

  }

  .select-menu {
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 100;
    max-height: 17.75rem;
    overflow: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: -5px;
    right: 0;
    background-color: white;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    padding: 1rem;
    box-sizing: border-box;

    .option-item {
      padding-left: 1rem;
      line-height: 3rem;
      color: gray;
      overflow-x: hidden;
      white-space: nowrap;
      text-overflow: ellipsis;
      margin: 0 -1rem;

      &:last-child {
        margin-bottom: 0;
      }

      &.selected,
      &:hover {
        background-color: lightgray;
        color: black;
      }

      &:focus {
        outline: none;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**How to use it:**

In template:

```
<form [formGroup]="mainFormGroup">
    <form-select formControlName="myControl" [options]="options">
     </form-select>
  </form>
```

in component:

```
const options = [{
        key: key1,
        label: 'value_1'
      }, {
        key: key2,
        label: 'value_2'
      }];

this.mainFormGroup = this.fb.group({
  myControl: ['']
});
```

Comment: I know how reactive forms work :) Here you have a custom component, usable within reactive forms and you can pass formControlName to it and having it perfectly bound with your formGroup. If you have a look at the docs, you see you have to implement ControlValueAccessor interface and this brings some methods to implement. You do not have to mess around with the code above, simply use it in the form.

Comment: I updated my answer with an example how to use it. As you see you just have to use it within your reactive form, you do not have to add anything.

Comment: Yes, we had to provide a specific layout for the options part, therefore this is (until now) the only way to achieve a completely custom result in a clean way.

Comment: I added them. In my project they were on a base class, so I did not see. Now you should have all. I also adjusted SelectFormModel, it is just an object with key and label. You can create a type for that if you want.

Comment: registerOnChange and registerOnTouch were missing. I added them. They are inner method of the ControlValueAccessor interface, not outputs.

Comment: ok what about `ControlValueAcessor` angular will throw if I don't implement a method I said I would. also I had to change `const match = this.options.find((item: { type?: string; params?: any }, index: number) => {` to  `const match = this.options.find((item, index) => {` because the interpreter didn't know what the heck I was talking about. what's going on there?

Comment: `Uncaught Error: Unexpected value 'undefined' declared by the module 'TrainingModule'` I suspect it's the providers syntax which is wrong from an Angular 8 point of view. are you sure you're not using Angular 1? how are you authorized to declare a const in the class's body? so much of your syntax is not up to current typescript grade.

Comment: I am using Angular 8 (you can see it from the decorators attributes) and in a working project. I simply copied some parts of code to give you an example to go on with. If you have an exception with a module, maybe it is related to your project. Did you declare the formSelect component correctly in your app? Eventually if you would create a stackBliz example I could try to help you further, otherwise it is quite hard for me to understand your setup.

Comment: actually stackblitz would be nice. I don't need any of my own components since none of them had errors. and my code is quite on-par with the latest rules. but like I said since you do some things I don't understand in your code, such as  specifying a complex type for item `item: { type?: string; params?: any }, index: number` when this is not the expected type or saying `implements ControlValueAccessor` but then never implementing it, the compilation crashes. Also I assumed that this would be placed inside `import` on ComponentModule. but when I did that, that's when I got the Undefined error.

Comment: you should have linked this https://blog.angularindepth.com/never-again-be-confused-when-implementing-controlvalueaccessor-in-angular-forms-93b9eee9ee83 or this  https://alligator.io/angular/custom-form-control/ or something else to me on the `ControlValueAccessor` bit. also not having the imports is tought to work with because at home I don't have my IDE and stackblitz doesn't auto-suggest imports. I have to google them one by one.

Comment: this is as far as I can get. I corrected a missing `}` closing curly brace line 55 and the imports and such but as you can see the code you gave me is not usable in its present state : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-itkpr5